# Invalid Version Error on running pip.main(['install,' numpy])

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, version

Trying to install using pip module using a python script

On running the following command to install the module numpy:

```
pip.main(['install', 'numpy'])
```

I get the following error:

```
pip._vendor.packaging.version.InvalidVersion: Invalid version: 'absl_py'
```

I get the same error for any module. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: There is no problem with the command you are using, so please provide us with the full code and with further information about the machine on which you are attempting to run it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Regardles of why this error happens: while `pip.main` might work for you at times, [Pip does not have a public API](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program). Even the docstring tries to dissuade you from using it in your own scripts:

```
This is an internal API only meant for use by pip's own console scripts.

For additional details, see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7498.
```

You are better of calling Pip's CLI via [`check_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call)/[`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), or using a project like [pip-api](https://pypi.org/project/pip-api/).

For example:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(["python", "-m", "pip", "install", "numpy"])
```